# Exit from an "if" in Delphi

Tags: delphi

you can exit a **while** loop with **break**.

How to exit from an **if**  .

Is there a kind of **GOTO** in Delphi ?

```
procedure ...
begin

  if .... then
    begin

      here the code to execute

      if (I want to exit = TRUE) then
        break or GOTO

      here the code not to execute if has exited

    end;

  here the code to execute

end;
```

Comment: How about a nested if? `if (I __don't__ want to exit) then  here the code not to execute if has exited end;`

Comment: you can use "exit" to exit form anywhere in a function|procedure

Comment: and use anonymouse procedures to use exit over any block statement :-)

Comment: Ahhhhhhrrrrggghhhh!  That code makes my skin crawl.   Just use another if statement to only do the things you want to do, and do nothing if you don't want to do it.

Comment: Learn to refactor your code so that you don't have giant blocks of code in it.  Each of these sub-blocks could be turned into a nicely named local procedure, at the very least, if they were not sensibly better made into methods of some object.

Comment: Local procedures, When only called once, break readability. Instead of reading and understanding you just continuously scroll back and forth more aimed and found "Damn! where is was reading it last time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exceptions.

Call an Abort in inner if or loop, and catch EAbort exception where u want to continue

```
procedure ...
begin

 try 
  if .... then
    begin

      (*      here the code to execute  *)

      if I_want-to-exit then Abort;

      (*      here the code not to execute if has exited *)

    end;
  
   except on E: EABORT do ;
   end;

   (*  here the code to execute *)
end;
```

UPD. Someone just upvoted this. Seems the topic is not burried dead long ago.
Ok, then giving a quick summary of what was burried in comments here and there.

This approach may be inferior to Marjan's try-exit-finally one, see his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11689392/976391

Exceptions are somewhat less expensive in Delphi, Borland held few patents on this, but still `finally` might be executing faster, than `raise`+`except`.

OTOH, this approach can be generalized to have several nested exitable if-blocks and different exit targets, due to exceptions cancelling and different classed can be used.
And i feel the code a bit cleaner, better expressing developer's (topic starter's) train of thought, when except-block is just an exit anchor, and the real code is after it, not inside it (as would be required for finally-solution).

```
type EExitException1 = class(Exception) end;
type EExitException2 = class(Exception) end;
procedure ...
begin

 try 
  if .... then
    begin

      (*      here the code to execute  *)
       try
         if .... then
         begin

            (*      here the nested code to execute  *)


            if I_want-to-exit then raise EExitException1.Create();

            (** ...  **)
            if I_want-to-exit-far-away then raise EExitException2.Create();

            (*      here the code not to execute if if-block cancelled *)

         end; // if

       (*      here the code to execute  *)  

       if I_want-to-exit-outer-if-here then raise EExitException2.Create();

        (*      here the code not to execute  *)  

       except on E: EExitException1 do ; end; // killing the exception
           
       (*      here the code to execute after the outer if-block exit *)

    end;

   (* one more piece of skippable code *)
  
   except on E: EExitException2 do ; end;

   (*  here the code to execute yet again *)
end;
```

This generalization, though, tends to quickly mutate into spaghetti too, just another kind of it.

Granted, the very problem seems nasty an is calling for refactoring of the whole piece. Without refactoring all the solutions would be messy one way or another. If ladders, plain old `goto`, flag vars - choose your poison. We can argue to death which one is less ugly, but ugly they all are.

Comment: +1 to offset the -1, not that I think this is elegant in any way, but it's the closest to using break imo. No other answer is actually answering the op question which is "is there a goto or break?", and this seems the closest to answering his question. Answering his question with 'nested ifs' isn't answering his question.

Comment: In my opinion the wrong way to use exceptions.
Better is to use
try
   if 123 then
      if 456 then
         exit;
finally
    // code is executed in any way even for the exit
end;

Comment: @John well, there is goto, surely goto is closer to goto than an exception

Comment: Very interesting - I never though of using exception this way ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan had the solution said "Abort" we wouldn't be so focused on using the exception.. if the try / except fits the bill anyway, then certainly abort is a valid solution to exiting an if/then.. if the try / except makes no sense other than using as a goto, then I agree.  Actually, a try/finally would be better as abort would leave the block and execute to finally

Comment: raising exceptions is 'expensive' (when used in a loop it can affect program execution speed)

Comment: Agree with @mjn, moreover such code is less readable than for instance [`try..finally`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11689392/960757).

Comment: it is not only less readable, it is also more fragile against later edits and restructuring.
It also might get LESS expensive in deep nested loops, where instead of 1% chance of raising exception you would always make 10*10*10*10 inline tests.
So if this part of code is speed-critical, yes, go goto, go assembler, go spaghetti and squeeze every CPU tact of it (and actually Delphi codegen is bad in speed). But if this code is not speed-critical (and most of codes are not) then readability and reallted on former maintainability do have their own value.

Comment: the comment above compares with extra flags in every if along the way.
try-finally approach is better provided that single exit route has place (single goto to replace) and you don't use other try-finally blocks much.

Answer (score 12):

Like [`Piskvor mentioned`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685841/exit-from-an-if-in-delphi#comment15493212_11685841), use nested if statement:

```
procedure Something;
begin    
  if IWantToEnterHere then
  begin
    // here the code to execute    
    if not IWantToExit then
      // here the code not to execute if has exited
  end;    
  // here the code to execute
end;
```

Comment: or: if IWantToStay then  :) also do not forget about "begin end" if you have multiple statements

Comment: +1 I agree with this one. Although Delphi supports goto and label, the usage leads to spagheti code and maintenance nightmare. Gotos and labels remind me of low-level language such as assembly.

Answer (score 4):

I am not in favour of using Exit's this way, but you asked for it...

Like @mrabat suggested in a comment to @Arioch 'The answer, you could use the fact that a finally block is always executed, regardless of Exit's and exceptions, to your advantage here:

```
procedure ...
begin

  if Cond1 then
  try
    // Code to execute

    if Cond2 then
      Exit;

    // Code NOT to execute if Cond2 is true
  finally
    // Code to execute even when Exit was called
  end;
end;
```

Comment: i pushed on EXCEPT for they allow different classes of exceptions act like different target labels. If there is only one bail-out route, then Finally approach is better of course. But if one would need defferent Exit-targets, then he would have something to specify landing zone. And if-flags in such scenario would quickly shadow genuine if conditions.
BTW, personally i think that code needing it might be akin for refactoring, if would be possible.

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, the smell rising from all kinds of if-flags in a single finally or from all kinds of specific exception types in an except block, does indicate an almost inescapable need for refactoring.

Answer (score 3):

This is commonly implemented like this:

```
function testOne: Boolean;
begin
  ...
end;

function testTwo: Boolean;
begin
  ...
end;

procedure runTests;
var
  bOK: Boolean;

begin
  bOK = True;

  if bOK then
  begin
    // Test something
    bOK = testOne;
    // If we passed, keep going
  end;

  if bOK then
  begin
    // Test something else
    bOK = testTwo;
    // If we passed, keep going
  end;

  ...
end;
```

Comment: +1, this makes the logic more clear.  I usually have the TestOne and TestTwo declared inside the runTests to make it clear where it belongs, as long as they cannot be reused somewhere else.

Comment: @LURD +1 for nested procedures - a nice encapsulation that I sorely miss in C++ etc, especially in message-handlers and the like that have a big case statement and lots of action procs called by each state.  If nothing else, I don't have to continually add new action procs to the class in a .h file <g>

Answer (score 2):

In general use of break or GOTO is not considered an elegant programming style.
I suggest you just invert your condition and say:

```
procedure ...
begin

  if .... then
    begin

    here the code to execute

    If (I want to exit <> TRUE) then
      here the code to execute if has exited( in your original code)

end;
```

here the code to execute

end;

Comment: "In general use of break or GOTO" I strongly disagree on this statement, consider a infinite loop, i.e. "while true do begin", how will you break the loop and continue with next expression without using "break"? also, "goto's and labels" are very powerful if used with care.

Comment: continue and break - yes. In FSMs for example. Random GOTO into every random part of code dangerous. KLater u move code into another unit, forget to fix goto - and it blows out randomly.

Comment: @DorinDuminica, my experience is that GOTO goes against maintainability and readability of the code. It is also true that in certain exams is not allowed. Of course, there is always the case in which they are required.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the different comments, I decided to post an answer to show how to use the [GoTo instruction](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Goto_Statements)... BTW, I prefer other methods explained in other answers avoiding its usage :

```
procedure ...
label
  CodeToExecute;
const
  iWantToExit = True;
begin
  if ... then
    begin
      ShowMessage('here the code to execute 1');
      if iWantToExit then
        goto CodeToExecute;

        ShowMessage('here the code not to execute if has exited');
    end;

CodeToExecute:
  ShowMessage('here the code to execute 2');

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use local `inline` procedure instead `GOTO` sentence;
`GOTO` sentence decrease visibility of you code.

```
procedure ...

  procedue Check; inline;
  begin
    if .... then
      begin

        here the code to execute

        if (I want to exit = TRUE) then
          exit;

        here the code not to execute if has exited

      end;
  end;

begin

  Check;

  here the code to execute

end;
```

Comment: I actually like this style - even better than using try finally blocks to circumvent the final exit.

Comment: with newer Delphi i'd maybe even made it using anonymous procedure, just declared and instantly called. Though less fast than local procedure, iot would be more readable. When complex function calls a lot of local procedures and each one is only called once - that just turns reading and understanding into scrolling training session :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to exit out of an 'if' block by using 'break'. Following example assumes that there are two edit boxes on the form. `repeat ... until true;` replaces the usual `begin ... end;`

```
   if ... then
   repeat
     Edit1.Text := 'test';
     if someCondition then 
       break;
     Edit2.Text := 'test';
   until true;
```

Edit: Clarification, the solution is just assuming the question is a brain teaser. This is not my recommended way to handle the situation and I will never use this in my code.

Comment: This code also works and answers. So i am plussing it to get it back to neutral zero. The problem itself is not elegant and all solutions have their drawbacks. Depressing some answer without comment WHY it is worse than other alternatives gave no valuable information.

Answer (score -1):

readeable code

// if cond1 then  if cond2 then if cond3 then -

```
procedure cond1_cond3;
begin

  if 
   not(Cond1) then exit;

cond1_work;

  if 
   not(Cond2) then exit;

cond2_work;

  if 
   not(Cond3) then exit;

cond3_work;


end;

procedure All_Work;

begin
   All_work_1;

   cond1_cond3; 

  All_work_2; 

end
```